# Getting Value From TextBox to URL

Tags: php, forms, url

I have a php code to generate link. (This code just add my URL before users URL.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $link = $_POST["link"];
        echo '<a href="http://onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url="$link"">Buy Now</a>';
    }
?>
<input type="url" class="form-control" name="link" placeholder="Enter Product URL" required>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

I want that Users URL get added after my URL. Like - http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url=(USERS URL) in echo as seen above. On submit the users get ans echo with a link which is added after my website URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$link = $_POST["link"];
echo '<a href="http://onlinedealsindia.in/go.php?url='.$link.'">Buy Now</a>';// corrected incorrect usage of quotes
}
?>
<form accept="" action="" method="post"> <!-- added form open -->       
<input type="url" class="form-control" name="link" placeholder="Enter Product URL" required>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> <!-- added form closing-->
```